# Right shift (Division) -> ROUND TOWARD ZERO

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am doing this..

```
value >> 3;
```

It is always going toward negative side.How do I round toward zero with right shift division?

Comment: Why are you dividing by 8 with a right shift? This is something the compiler should be doing for you.

Comment: Two's complement representation causes negatives when divided to round toward floor. How to fix this?
Also a quote from wikipedia "On an "N's-complement" architecture (for radix "N") an arithmetic shift is equivalent to a division that rounds towards negative infinity, not towards zero. "

Comment: Oh please.. this is a puzzle..

Comment: I don't understand what it being a puzzle has to do with writing unreadable code. Have you checked how normal division rounds?

Comment: Didn't say I didn't care, just that it wouldn't stop me from opening my big trap and boring you all with my loquaciousness. I can loquate with the best of 'em :-) With apologies to Julius Caesar from Asterix and Obelix, from whom that's paraphrased. Anyway, @RealHIFIDude is on 60% as we speak so it worked.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you *want* truncated rather than floored division?  I can only think of one case where I might have been able to find it useful, but many where I had to go through annoying gyrations to get a floored result.

Answer (score 6):

Gez, the answers were pretty bad ; you want to solve that without branching, but without breaking your positive numbers either.

Here it is :

```
(int)(value+(((unsigned)value)>>31)) >> 3
```

The cast to (unsigned) is required to perform a logical shift and obtain just the sign bit, then we need to cast back to (int) to perform an arithmetic right shift.

The code above made the assumption that your int data type is 32 bits, you should of course use data types such as int32_t in such cases.

Comment: Correction!
For a division by 8 ( or shift by 3 ), you would actually need to add 7 times the sign bit ( or numerator - 1 ) ; not once as in the example above, which would work for a shift by 1 ( or a division by 2 ).

So, in other words, something like :
uint32_t signbit=((uint32_t)value)>>31;
result = ((int32_t)(value+(signbit<<shift)-signbit))>>shift;

Answer (score 3):

Do something conditionally depending on whether your value is positive or negative.

```
if( value < 0 ) {
    -((-value) >> 3);
}
else {
    value >> 3;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following expression instead:

```
(value < 0) ? -((-value) >> 3) : value >> 3;
```

That will force a negative number to be positive first so that it round towards zero, then changes the result back to negative.

This may cause issues for the minimum integer under two's complement notation (not ones' complement or sign/magnitude) but you could put a separate check in to catch that first.

Or (and this is probably preferable) you could just *stop* trying to divide by eight with a right shift altogether, instead choosing:

```
value = value / 8;
```

Then let your compiler choose the best way of doing that. You should be coding to specify *intent* rather than trying to optimise (needlessly, unless you have a truly brain-dead compiler).

Comment: It _may_ not work for INT_MIN. ISO only guarantees the minimum range compatible with 1s complement and sign/magnitude (e.g, -32767..+32767). So, yes, you _may_ get into trouble with 2s complement but it's by no means guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```
(value + 4) >> 3
```

Comment: But the positives when divided are going up by 1 :(

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand your question properly. If you change it to ((value + 3) >> 3) do you get what you want ?

Comment: @AdamPierce: He wants to round towards zero.

Answer (score 1):

Add 7 to the number if it is negative in order to round to zero.

This is how you do that:

```
int mask = x >> 31;
x = (x + (7 & mask)) >> 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering 'signed' shifting, when what you seem to want is unsigned shifting. Try casting it to unsigned first, like this

```
x = ((unsigned) x) >> 3;
```

.. or you could just use division.