# C programme bitwise: value of -1 >> 1

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

For GCC 32 bits, -1 >> 1 returns me FFFFFFFF, but I thought after 2's complement, I will get
0111 1111 ... 1111 which should be 7fff ffff. did i miss something?

Comment: "but I thought after 2's complement" - shifting has nothing to do with  2's complement

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180157/what-is-the-value-of-0-in-c/23180242#23180242.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Right bit-shift giving wrong result, can someone explain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176797/right-bit-shift-giving-wrong-result-can-someone-explain)

Comment: you are missing three points: One is answer below, (2) How 2'complement works (3) there is concept of signed and unsigned shifts --- negative numbers in most C implementation preserves sign but hence are === to arithmetic shifts, to perform unsigned shift use `unsigned(-1) >> 1`. Read my answer [what is the value of ~0 in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23180179/1673391) to get some idea,  let me know if you have confusion I will post an answer.

Comment: Sorry I mean `((unsigned)-1) >> 1);`  see code @ [codepad](http://codepad.org/PPrnpJzi) outputs `2147483647` that is `7F FF FF FF`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under **most** implementations, that operator does an `arithmetic shift` for signed types, so it preserves the `sign` bit (which is the leftmost bit), in this case `1`.

As @Clifford correctly pointed out, the language standard leaves the implementation of `>>` up to the implementor.

See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) for details.

Comment: No - it is implementation defined behavior for negative values.  An implementation may replace the vacated bit with 0 or 1.  What you have described here is "typical" behavior (and may even be universal), but it is not guaranteed by the language definition.

Comment: @Clifford, That is true. I will amend it to be more careful about the wording.

Comment: @Clifford, Updated. Please let me know if anything else is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

For `E1 >> E2`, if `E1` is negative, then the behavior is implementation-defined, which means different compilers could use different strategies to implement it.

Apparently GCC choose arithmetic shift, as pointed out by @merlin2011