# 32 bit Integer Overflow

Tags: c++

Why making an  int -2147483648 to positive overflow int.

```
int x = -2147483648;
int num;
if(x<0)
{
   num = -x; //overflow here
}
```

For ex:below both x and y are same.

```
int x = -2147483648;
cout<<x<<endl;
int y = -x;
cout<<x<<endl;

Output:
-2147483648
-2147483648
```

Comment: Because it doesn't fit in a 32 bit signed int?

Comment: The valid range for a 32 bit integer is -2147483648 to 2147483647. `2147483648` is too large for a 32 bit signed int.

Comment: Note that before C++20 the official rules for the results of signed integer overflow are that [there are no rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: @drescherjm
How it is one greater while negative than for positive .

Suppose 2 bit integer..

00 => 0,
01 => 1,
10 => 2,
11 => 3,

the same for negative max it can go to -3 , or in this range can be -4 to 3 .

Comment: [Here is a neat question on what happens in c++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363324). TL;DR version: This is still UB.

Comment: @sanjeev there’s always one more negative than positive. So a 3 bit signed number would be -4 to 3. This is because there are an even number of total representable numbers and zero has to take one of them. This leads to having an odd number of representations left which means you can’t have equal number of positive and negative numbers. This is called twos-complement. An alternate but generally unused representation is sign/magnitude which does have the same range but can also represent negative zero.

Comment: ***How it is one greater while negative than for positive*** Because there is 1 zero not 2.

Comment: Related C++ 'joke': `cout << abs(INT_MIN) << endl;`.

Comment: @ Mike Vine Thanks got your point.

For someone like me below link can also be useful to understand

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement