# Why does g++-11 '-O2' contain a bug while '-O0' is ok?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++20, internal-compiler-error

```
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T f(T const a = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(),
    T const b = std::numeric_limits<T>::max())
{
    if (a >= b)
    {
        throw 1;
    }

    auto n = static_cast<std::uint64_t>(b - a + 1);
    if (0 == n)
    {
        n = 1;
    }

    return n;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f<int>() << std::endl;
}
```

`g++-11 -std=c++20 -O2` should output `0` other than `1`!

clang++ is ok as expected. If I change `-O2` to `-O0`, g++-11 is also ok.

See: [online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b6PhchT3s)

**Why does g++** `-O2` **contain a bug while** `-O0` **is ok?**

Comment: Why the C++11-tag when you compile with c++20? One of them is incorrect.

Comment: Weird.  If you just do `std::cout << (std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - std::numeric_limits<int>::min() + 1);` in GCC, it prints the value of `0`: https://godbolt.org/z/nn8fsnj8Y

Comment: Isn't `b - a` signed overflow?

Comment: I wonder if it is some off by one error the optimizer has and it's compile time computation is 1 less then it should be.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are `int`, with values `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` respectively, then `b - a + 1` is computed as an `int`, and the result of that calculation overflows an `int`, so causes undefined behaviour.   So both compilers are correct, regardless of optimisation flags.

Comment: @Peter which is now well defined in C++20

Comment: I click your demo link and it show me that result is 0 like it should be.

Comment: Well tags now changed again from C++20 to C++11 so we're in UB again :D

Comment: The reasons gcc contains bugs is because it is software. clang and other compilers also have their own bugs. Only the most trivial software is bug-free.

Comment: @RichardCritten - My understanding is that C++20 requires twos-complement, but that overflow of signed integral types remains undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter You I think you are correct - trying to find a definitive quote

Comment: Hmm and now we're back to C++20. OP trying to trick us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ramifications of C++20 requiring two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363324/ramifications-of-c20-requiring-twos-complement)  _"...This was explicitly considered and people felt that the best option was keeping it __undefined behavior__...."_

Comment: I wouldn't describe this as "definitive", but http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4878.pdf (the most recent C++20 draft according to  https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/wd-index.md ) has a note in Section 6.8.2 after the second para stating "[Note 2: Unsigned arithmetic does not overflow. Overflow for signed arithmetic yields undefined behavior (7.1).— end note]".   I haven't looked further (and I don't have a ratified version of the latest C++ standard handy at present) but it is pretty ... suggestive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b - a + 1` is clearly UB when the type of `a` and `b` are `int` and `a` is `INT_MIN` and `b` is `INT_MAX` as signed overflow is undefined behavior.

From [cppreference:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

> When signed integer arithmetic operation overflows (the result does not fit in the result type), the behavior is undefined

You are not converting to `int64_t` until after the calculation has already been executed.

Comment: C++20 mandates twos compliment for signed integers now

Comment: Weird, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic doesn't mention the new rules for c++20

Comment: Even though c++20 enforces 2's complement signed integers, it does not state anything new about overflows in this context

Comment: @Mestkon Cppreference hasn't caught up yet.  See the actual standard text here: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.integral#3

Comment: @NathanOliver That rule is about integer conversions. It doesn't apply to arithmetic overflow.

Comment: @NathanOliver The rule that says overflow is UB is https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.pre#4 That technically applies to all numeric types, so the rule excluding unsigned must be somewhere else. I found a non-normative note but not an actual rule https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.fundamental#note-2.

Comment: @eerorika Yeah, looks like I need to readjust how much that change actually did.

Comment: @NathanOliver The change basically gives standard defined (as opposed to implementation defined) behaviour for conversions to smaller signed integer type as well as reinterpretation casts between signed and unsigned. And I guess the exact range of values for signed types depending on width.

Comment: @NathanOliver it was deemed _too harmful_ to define signed overflow behavior, as it would disrupt existing compiler optimizations that assume signed overflow "never happens".