# Does C++ use the two's complement for its representation of integers?

Tags: c++, types, binary

Does this depend on the C++ version, OS, and/or system architecture? Does `long`, `long long`, `int`, `short`, and even custom integer types from all/most packages, use the same sign system?

I am learning about shifting, masking, and other forms of bit-manipulation, so this will help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363324/ramifications-of-c20-requiring-twos-complement

Comment: Caution, that even though the two's complement is *now* guaranteed, you can still run afoul of **undefined behavior** with shifting.  Best to do bit twiddling with unsigned integers.

Comment: "*Does this depend on the C++ version, OS, and/or system architecture?*" - all of the above